# Finding tensor indices

Tags: matlab, indices

I am building a 5-d tensor which explores a function in a 5-D space. The tensor is just the values of the function in discrete points in the space.

But, whenever I get the value, I want to get the indices of tensor / coordinate of space for later visualization. I tried to construct linspace-s for particular dimensions, then do a "sort of tensor exterior product". When I call the indices, I get the coordinate. It didn't work.

I hope I can get the indices with the value of the tensor at those indices, so I can rescale the indices into my coordinate. Is there such a function?

For example - 
A =

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

For visualization, I want to plot A(:,2), a slice at fixed column. The coordinates are (1,2),(2,2),(3,2).
I want to plot f = (2,5,8) with coordinate = (1,2,3)
But now I have to generalize it into 5 dimensions and extract data for 2D colour plot (fix the other 3 dimensions)

Comment: If you can, please add a code example and point out where you are stuck.

Comment: What you want can probably be done, but it's unclear from your question. Please reword and include an example with input and desired output